# ngIf gives 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'visit' of undefined' when indexing into array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an ngIf inside an ngFor and I use the index to check whether the item at that index of an array is equal to a certain value but whenever I try to index anything it gives a

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'visit' of undefined 
at AstTranslator.translate (<projdirectory>/node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\expression.js:81:24)
```

```
progress.component.ts 
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-progress',
    templateUrl: './progress.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./progress.component.scss']
})
export class ProgressComponent implements OnInit {
    temp = [
             "Complete",
            "NotAttempted",
            "NotAttempted",
            "NotAttempted",
            "NotAttempted",
            "NotAttempted",
            "NotAttempted" 
           ]
    tasks = [some array of same length]
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

}
```

```
progress.component.html

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      
        <table class = "items">
            <thead>
                <tr class = "header-row">
                    <th class = "title-header">Title</th>
                    <th class = "due-header">Due Date</th>
                    <th class = "status-header">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <tr *ngFor="let task of tasks; let index = index">
                    <td>{{ task.title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ task.dueDate}}</td>
                    <td>
                       <div class = "complete" *ngIf="temp[index]==='Complete'">Complete </div>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand how temp is undefined since it is hardcoded?
rough stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xdk4jr?file=package.json
let me know if other files are required.

Comment: your error says cannot read property 'visit', but there is no visit in your code

Comment: yea I'm also confused why it says that

Comment: it says something about AstTranslator.translate, maybe you should check your library ... are you sure the error is in the file you provided ?

Comment: Would you be able to put up a running stackblitz for this?

Comment: it works on stackblitz, which is weird. I guess it could be my node modules but I'm not sure what the AstTranslator is part of and what to do

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue and these steps helped:

- Delete your `node_modules` folder
- Run `npm cache clean --force`
- Run `npm install`
- Run `ng s`

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

you have a logic problem with your code.

your **temp** array is fixed list with 7 items

**tasks** is unknown number of items.

you are looping through tasks and (for some reason) getting the index item of the task element to compare. meaning if you have more than 7 tasks, you will be trying to access temp[7] which is undefined.

it would be better code if you set up your data like this:

```
var taskItems = [{task: task1, status: 'Complete;},
  //etc.
];
```

and then html:

```
*ngFor= "let task of taskItems"

*ngIf="task.status == 'Complete'"
```

or if you don't like that solution, add this to the html:

```
*ngIf="temp && temp.length > index && temp[index]==='Complete'"
```

Comment: I focus only on frontend and backend is handled by someone else.  I only created mock data following the structure it would be returned from when everything is set up. And both arrays have the same length.

Comment: well obviously they aren't the same length. you could add this code to the html: `*ngIf="temp && temp.length > index && temp[index]==='Complete'"`. that should fix the error.

Comment: it doesn't fix it, even if I just do temp[0] it gives the same error. I know its probably my libraries that are causing the issue but even deleting and reinstalling didn't change it